# Detect the internal storage memory?

Tags: android, filesystems, android-sdcard

I am working on an app which moves a file from sdcard to internal memory storage .What I need is :

1.To detect the size of the file to be moved.

2.Detect the size of free memory in internal storage.

3.Compare both?

This would give some alert whenever the free memory is less than the size of the file.
How can I do the first two points.If anyone worked on similar type of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar, but then for multiple (music) files in a directory, and across any mount point available to the system. I'm not 100% sure the explanation below will be applicable for the internal storage, but it should at least give you some useful pointers.

You can easily get the size of a file by calling [`.length()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#length%28%29) on it:

```
long fileSize = someFile.length();
```

Note that in case `someFile` is actually a directory, the result is not defined. Hence, to get a directory's size, iterate over all its children (which on its turn may again contain directories of course).

For retrieving information about the file system's space, I used the [`statFs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) class, which is nothing more but a Java wrapper for `statfs()`. Calculating the available space is a simple multiplication:

```
// 'fromFreeBytes' is the source file/directory size
StatFs toDirStats = new StatFs(mToDir.getAbsolutePath());
long toFreeBytes = ((long)toDirStats.getAvailableBlocks() * (long)toDirStats.getBlockSize());
if (toFreeBytes < fromFreeBytes) {
    //insufficient available space
}
```

Finally, it's important to remember that if you're going to move files between different mount points, you **cannot** use File's [`renameTo(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) method. In stead you'll have to use an InputStream and OutputStream to copy the data across.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1. `long file_size = file.length();`
2. `File data_path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
   StatFs stat = new StatFs(data_path.getPath());
   long free_internal_memory = stat.getBlockSize() * stat.getAvailableBlocks();`